# Problema com retorno de POST utilizando Synapse

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Estou realizando uma requisição POST no Delphi XE7 utilizando o Synapse (Synalist). Peguei apenas a parte onde faço o método POST e realizo minhas tentativas de conversão do resultado.

Acima disso eu declaro propriedades como userAgent, headers e cookies.

O método UTF8FileTo88591 eu peguei deste link: [UTF8FileTo88591](https://www.wenbiancheng.com/question/delphi/5500293-HttpGetText(),%20autodetect%20charset,%20and%20convert%20source%20to%20UTF8)

```
var
  http: THTTPSend;
  stl : TstringList;
  ss  : TStringStream;
begin
  if http.HTTPMethod('POST', edtUrMenu.text) then
  begin
    HTTP.Document.position := 0;
    HTTP.Document.saveToFile('d:\a\a3.txt');

    UTF8FileTo88591('d:\a\a3.txt'); // tentativa 1

    stl.defaultEncoding := TEncoding.UTF8; // tentativa 2
    stl.loadFromStream(http.document);
    stl.saveToFile('D:\a\LoadFromStream.txt');

    // tentativa 3
    try
      ss := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
      HTTP.Document.position := 0;
      ss.CopyFrom(HTTP.Document, 0);
      ss.SaveToFile('d:\a\a4.txt');
      showmessage(ss.datastring);
    except
    end;
    ss.free;
  end;
end;
```

O problema é que o resultado está com codificação ao qual não consegui converter. Uma parte do resultado (gerado através do **HTTP.Document.saveToFile('d:\a\a3.txt')**) ou [pastebin com o resultado completo](https://pastebin.com/iKcfQcXw)

```
‹      í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"~ãäñïúôË“7¿ÏËÓtÞ.ÊôåWOžŸ¤mß½ûÝ{'wï>}ó4ý½¿ýæ‹çéîx'}SgË¦h‹j™•wïž¾ø(ýhÞ¶«Gwï^]]¯î«úâî›WwßÖ.^Ö_·[ïÍñ¬}tô'Ô9¾Lß-ÊeóYÒîÃ‡ÀG)µ<Ï³YZÌ>ûhÚ–;;¿ÿ·éÏÝŽ·E[æôý-ÑMÞ¦/ò«iµ¤7îÊwy›¥è`;ÿEëâò³~ïí¯Ž·OªÅ*k‹I™”Rû6_¶Ÿ}tvúÙéb]fm~vúð£ônäå“l:Ïémê®"Ôì«Ëj{Š¯ø­²X¾Mçu~þÙGãñÝŸnîN›ænu™×Ó¬iïþô/ZçõõöºÓÇ¥u^~öQÓ^—y3Ïóö£´½^åŸ}ÔæïZ¼X,§åz–7w¿È—ëßŸpÉÚ¯Jqk³  þk(DÞfZ«Öÿî§³ËL>Å§ô\feY]½È/ˆÒ—
```

Comment: Se esta utilizando o XE7 porque não utilizar a `Indy` para essa requisição?

Comment: Eu tentei com o Indy, mas tive outros problemas e acredito que tenha sido por causa dos cookies ou o fato de que precisava deixar a conexão ativa a qualquer custo (keep-alive). Eu consegui resolver o problema da pergunta, o conteúdo que estava recebendo era um GZIP, usei uma lib pra descomprimir o resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui identificar o problema e resolver a situação. O conteúdo que recebo é um gzip, identifiquei isso pois no header eu só recebia um resultado caso colocasse o seguinte header, sem o header ou caso aceitasse outro tipo de encoding eu não recebo o conteúdo (301 http code):

```
http.headers.add('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br');
```

Portanto fui atrás e encontrei a seguinte biblioteca: [GZip](https://www.gocher.me/GZIP) ao qual usei a função *unzipStream* e então consegui ter o dado descomprimido.

```
ss := TStringStream.create;
b := unzipStream(http.document,ss);
ss.saveToFile('D:\a\a4.txt');
```